# I need help to change dataframe columns and index to set this as values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-conversion

The idea is convert:

Currently sliced df

|  | Arica y Parinacota | Tarapacá | Antofagasta | Atacama | Coquimbo | Valparaíso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marzo | 6 | 10 | 35 | 2 | 28 | 15 |

df that I need

| Month | Region | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marzo | Arica y Parinacota | 6 |
| Marzo | Tarapacá | 10 |
| Marzo | Antofagasta | 35 |
| Marzo | Atacama | 2 |
| Marzo | Coquimbo | 28 |
| Marzo | Valparaíso | 115 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to preserve index values by reset_index

```
df2 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars= 'index', var_name = ['Region'], value_name = 'number').rename(columns= {'index': 'month'})
```

another solution would be to use pandas [stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['month', 'region', 'number']
```

Comment: Pavan Suvarna thanks for answer, and sorry for the way that I presented the first df, I meant that index is the index of the dataframe.